# mod_pagespeed no longer rewrite resources

Tags: apache2, mod-pagespeed

I have a webserver with PHP 7.4, and have used mod_pagespeed for a long time to speed things up.

But it's stopped working lately and I cannot figure out why. In my error logs I have lots of lines like this:

```
[pagespeed:warn] [pid 17853] [mod_pagespeed 1.13.35.2-0 @17853] 12029550x267x9435speilvendes-dallas.jpg:0: Resource based on https://example.no/bilder/9435speilvendes-dallas.jpg but cannot access the original
```

If I run the website with ?PageSpeedFilters=+debug I get a lot of these things in the source

`<!--Uncacheable content, preventing rewriting of https://example.no/design/js/uploadfile.min.css-->`

I've searched high and low for people with similar problems, trying to add settings for SSL to in pagespeed.conf, confirming that I can fetch the original resources from terminal etc. But i just can't get it to work.

Any ideas are welcome :)

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? Having the same problem and I can't find anything helpful either.

Comment: @RichCourt, no I didn't really find a great solution. Increasing Apache workers on the server help a bit. And I actually moved some of the resources to another server  to split the load.

Comment: Thanks for replying  The search continues I guess